# Why is $\mathbb{P}(F\geqslant G) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(F \geqslant g | G=g) \, D_G(g) \text{d}g$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

For random variables $F,G$  I have problems with understanding the equation

$$\mathbb{P}(F \geqslant G) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(F \geqslant g | G=g) \, D_G(g) \text{d}g, $$

where $D_G$ is the density function of $G$.

Why is this correct? I know that we can write 
$\mathbb{P}(F \geqslant G)=  \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbb{P}(F \geqslant G)\, D_G(g) \text{d}g $ but I am not sure how to deal with the conditional probability.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about [conditional expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)? For random variable $X$ and continuous random variable $Y$ jointly defined on the same probability space, "$\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant Y)=  \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbb{P}( X\geqslant y)\, f_Y(y) \text{d}y$" is true *if the random variables in question are independent*; it does not hold in general. More generally, using the indicator function ${\bf 1}_{X\geqslant Y}$,

$$
P(X\geqslant Y) = \mathbb E[{\bf 1}_{X\geqslant Y}]  = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[{\bf 1}_{X\geqslant Y}\vert Y]] = \mathbb E[P(X\geqslant Y\vert Y)] \\= \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbb{P}( X\geqslant y\ \vert\ Y=y)\, f_Y(y) \text{d}y
\tag{1}$$
The first 3 equalities follow by definition. The last, because $Y$ is a continuous random variable.

---

For example, as indicated in the comments, for jointly continous random variables $X$ and $Y$, we define the function $P(X\geqslant y\vert Y=y):=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\bf 1}_{x\geqslant y}\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}\text dx$ and, indeed rather trivially, see that

$$
P(X\geqslant Y) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P(X\geqslant y\vert Y=y)f_{Y}(y)\text dy = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Bigl(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\bf 1}_{x\geqslant y}\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}\text dx\Bigr)f_{Y}(y)\text dy = \\\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\bf 1}_{x\geqslant y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text dx\text dy,\\
$$

where the far *rhs*, by definition of the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$, must equal the far *lhs*. The important point to note here is that, in a rigorous sense, this example is unsurprisingly consistent and works because the relationships and entities in (1) are already well-defined.

Comment: I know the following definition:$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega_0): = \mathbb{E}[X | Y= Y(\omega_0)]:= \mathbb{E}[\chi_{\{\omega \in \Omega \colon Y(\omega) = Y(\omega_0)\}} \cdot X]. $$

Comment: Does $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ hold, if $X,Y$ are not independet, too? I have the following:

$$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] = \int_{\Omega}  \mathbb{E}[\chi_{\{\omega \in \Omega \colon Y(\omega) = Y(\omega_0)\}} \cdot X]\, \text{d} \mathbb{P}(\omega_0)= \int_{\Omega}  \int_{\Omega} \chi_{\{\omega \in \Omega \colon Y(\omega) = \\ Y(\omega_0)\}}(x) \cdot X(x) \, \text{d} \mathbb{P}(x)\text{d} \mathbb{P}(\omega_0)$$

Comment: @user144697, No, in answer to your first comment, I am referring to the requirements that whetever function we label as $\mathbb E[X\vert Y]$ must be $\sigma (Y)$- measurable and, for $A\in\sigma(Y)$, $\mathbb E[{\bf 1}_{A}X] = \mathbb E[{\bf 1}_{A}\mathbb E[X\vert Y]]$.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(Y)]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ is always true and $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ iff $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: For which equality in your calculation do you need independence of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @user144697, None of the equalities need independence; that is the point. If you impose independence on the general case in my answer, then $P(X\geqslant y\vert Y=y) = P(X\geqslant y)$ and the assertion you made when you wrote "I know that we can write..." holds. Also, note that since you have correctly asserted that $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\vert Y]] = \mathbb E[X]$ always, you should be suspicious of whether the integrals (or definition of conditional expectation) you wrote in your second comment make sense.

Comment: Last question: Why do we have $\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y](\omega) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq Y | Y = Y(\omega))$ and the random-variable on the right side should be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable?

Comment: Is my interpretation $ \omega \mapsto \mathbb{P}( \{\omega' \in \Omega : X(\omega' ) = Y (\omega' )\} | \{ \omega' \in \Omega : Y(\omega' ) = Y(\omega) \}) $ of $\mathbb{P}(X \geq Y | Y)$ true?

Comment: @user144697, One can (and should?) define $P(X\geqslant Y\vert Y)$ as being alternative notation for the well-defined $\mathbb E[{\bf 1}_{X\geqslant Y}\vert Y]$. In the particular case that $P(X\geqslant y\vert Y = y)$ is also well-defined (e.g. by means of joint pdfs), then we can show that $P(X\geqslant y\vert Y = y)$ is a function (out of possibly many functions) consistent with the properties of the conditional expectation/probability $P(X\geqslant Y\vert Y)$. When in doubt, rely on definitions and first principles!

Comment: If I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y]$, which is defined as $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y]:= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | \sigma(Y)]$, I have to find a random-variable $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y]$ which is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, with the property, that for all $B \in \sigma(Y)$ it holds that

$$\int_B \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y](\omega) \text{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) =\int_B \mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y}(\omega)\text{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) .$$

Comment: The problem is, so far,  $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X \geq Y} | Y]$ is only a symbol for this random random variable. So I still have problems, understanding the last step. (The equality $\int_{\Omega} Y(\omega) \, \text{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} y f_Y(y) \, \text{d}y$ is clear.)

Comment: @user144697, So, given a particular probability model, define the function $P(X\geqslant y\vert Y=y)$ in a "natural" way and convince yourself that this defined function is a bona-fide conditional expectation. For instance, for jointly continuous $X$ and $Y$, $$P(X\geqslant y\vert Y=y):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\bf 1}_{x\geqslant y} \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}\text dx.$$

Comment: @user144697, Out of curiosity, the downvote is because?